# PowerShell: manage suggested apps

Tags: powershell, windows-store-apps, windows-10-universal, startmenu

In my Windows 10 start menu, under Pinned Tiles, I have two *suggested apps*: Asphalt8Airborne and Microsoft.AgeCastles. I do not know if the term "suggested" fits here, anyway, contrary to other preinstalled apps, when you try to run them, you are only redirected to the store app, where you are proposed to download them.

I would like to manage them in PowerShell, but:

```
Get-AppxPackage "GAMELOFTSA.Asphalt8Airborne" 
Get-AppxPackage Microsoft.AgeCastles*
```

returns nothing.
Also:

```
(New-Object -Com Shell.Application).NameSpace('shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}').Items() | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Property Name
```

or

```
Get-StartApps | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Property Name
```

return no reference to them.

Where is the suggested app list stored and how can I list them in PowerShell?

Comment: If your purpose is to remove them [your title will return some results](https://www.google.com/search?q=PowerShell:+manage+suggested+apps) on google.

Comment: @LotPings: of course i googled a bit, but found nothing addressing Powershell. Do you have a specific link?